# randint() only generating high values and not drawing enough objects

Tags: python, random, graphics

For this project, I need to draw 400 different squares at random spots, and are all at least 5 pixels away from each other. Currently, boxes are mostly drawn on the bottom of the window, and only about half are drawn before the program freezes. I've consulted my professors, and they are stumped.

```
#Importing things I need
import random
from graphics import *

def enterValue(used_spots, y_spots, corner1, corner2):
    #enters the value where our square starts into the array, if it's a
    #valid value.
    used_spots.append(corner1)
    y_spots.append(corner2)

def checkPlace(used_spots,y_spots,corner1,corner2):
    #checks the placement of every square to see if our new one is valid.
    # the total size of a square is 20px edge + 5 px Border + 3 px width.
    # So we need to check based on that number.
    slot=0
    check=0
    for slot in range(0,len(used_spots)):
        #if the distance between the squares is more than 28 pixels, return
        # true. Else, stop checking and return false
        if abs(corner1-used_spots[slot])<28 and abs(corner2-y_spots[slot]<28):
            check=0
            break
        else:
            check=1
    return check

def randomCorners():
    #gets us a random variable for x and y of a box's corner
    corner1=random.randint(3,1800-28)
    corner2=random.randint(3,900-28)
    return corner1, corner2

def drawBox(corner1,corner2,EDGE,WIDTH,colors,win):
    #Draws the box
    point1=Point(corner1,corner2)
    point2=Point(corner1+EDGE,corner2+EDGE)
    square=Rectangle(point1,point2)
    square.setWidth(WIDTH)
    square.setFill(random.choice(colors))
    square.draw(win)

def main():
    #delcaring variables
    corner1=0
    corner2=0
    used_spots=[]
    y_spots=[]
    WIDTH=3
    EDGE=20
    colors=["red","orange","yellow","blue","pink","green"]
    win=GraphWin("MAINWINDOW",1800,900)
    win.setBackground("white")

    #Draws a random box at a random spot, then makes a spot for a new potential box
    #and tests it
    corner1,corner2=randomCorners()
    drawBox(corner1,corner2,EDGE,WIDTH,colors,win)
    enterValue(used_spots,y_spots,corner1,corner2)
    corner1,corner2=randomCorners()

    while len(used_spots) < 400:
        #If we can draw a box there, draw it and add coords to the lists,
        #then generates a new set of coordinates.
        if checkPlace(used_spots,y_spots,corner1,corner2)==1:
            drawBox(corner1,corner2,EDGE,WIDTH,colors,win)
            enterValue(used_spots,y_spots,corner1,corner2)

         #otherwise, make a new coordinate and try again.
        corner1,corner2=randomCorners()

main()
```

Comment: I get `ImportError: No module named 'graphics'`.

Comment: `graphics` is not a standard Python module. Where did it come from and how can others get it?

Comment: you can get it here http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py just copy and paste it into a python file and save it wherever your file is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `checkPlace` function:

```
if abs(corner1-used_spots[slot])<28 and abs(corner2-y_spots[slot]<28):
```

Should be

```
if abs(corner1-used_spots[slot])<28 and abs(corner2-y_spots[slot])<28:
```

(note position of last parenthesis).

Your code was passing the result of the less than comparison to the `abs` function, rather than using the result of the `abs` function in the comparison.

So, whenever `corner2` was less than `y_spots[slot] + 28`, the condition would evaluate to true (because `abs` wasn't called until after the comparison), meaning that lower values (the top of the screen) would trigger it and be rejected if they also met the other condition. Eventually there would be enough entries in `used_spots` and `y_spots` that at least one was always triggering both conditions in the `if` and the program locks up, stuck in an infinite loop trying to find valid co-ordinates.